# Why program dont convert hryvnias into Euro?

Tags: c#

Write a program that convert hryvnias into $, Euro.

Good time of day.
I tried to write a program that takes the current exchange rate from the official site. Please correct my mistakes and add comments that I did wrong. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Net;


namespace Currency_Converter
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the amount of hryvnia: ");
        double uah = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double cource = GetCourse();
        Console.WriteLine("Euro exchange rate: " + cource);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} UAH. = {1} Euro.", uah, 
            Math.Round(uah / GetCourse(), 2));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static double GetCourse()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string data = 
client.DownloadString("https://bank.gov.ua/ua/markets/exchangerates? 
date=20.02.2021&period=daily");
        string ff = data.Substring(data.IndexOf("<td>33,6478</td>"));
        ff = ff.Substring(ff.IndexOf("<td>") + 4);
        ff = ff.Remove(ff.IndexOf("</td>")).Replace('.', ',');
        return double.Parse(ff);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: What is the problem you meet with your code? What do you see what you interpreted as "dont convert"?

Comment: Enter the amount of hryvnia: 500
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex')
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex)

Comment: Always test the result of an IndexOf call before using it! One-liners are one of the most costly newbie errors

Comment: At the first glance: you retrieve exchange rate twice. Use the value retrieved first here: `Math.Round(uah / cource, 2 )`

Comment: `data.IndexOf("<td>33,6478</td>")`? If you know the rate (33,6478) why are asking it from a website? The parsing logic isn't good, at least it is missing "EUR" :)

Comment: Currency exchange rates are subject to change. How do I get it from a government website?

Comment: ?->     Console.WriteLine("{0} UAH. = {1} Euro.", uah, 
                Math.Round(uah / GetCourse()));      => NO

Comment: Please check the answer below. You should not use the website at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the web crowling as there is an official API:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the amount of hryvnia: ");
            double uah = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double cource = GetCourse();
            Console.WriteLine("Euro exchange rate: " + cource);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} UAH. = {1} Euro.", uah,
                Math.Round(uah / cource, 2));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static double GetCourse()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string data = client.DownloadString("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json");
            var currencies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root[]>(data);
            return currencies.Where(c => c.cc.Equals("EUR", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).First().rate;
        }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int r030 { get; set; }
        public string txt { get; set; }
        public double rate { get; set; }
        public string cc { get; set; }
        public string exchangedate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UPD. It is more recommended using the HttpClient. I prefer the Newtonsoft.Json but you can use any other library like [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the amount of hryvnia: ");
            double uah = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double cource = GetCourse();
            Console.WriteLine("Euro exchange rate: " + cource);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} UAH. = {1} Euro.", uah,
                Math.Round(uah / cource, 2));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static double GetCourse()
        {
            Task<double> task = Task.Run(async () => await GetCourseAsync());
            return task.Result;
        }

        static async Task<double> GetCourseAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var currencies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root[]>(data);
            return currencies.Where(c => c.cc.Equals("EUR", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).First().rate;
        }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int r030 { get; set; }
        public string txt { get; set; }
        public double rate { get; set; }
        public string cc { get; set; }
        public string exchangedate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! But WebClient is deprecated by MS: 
We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0
 Important

Comment: Agree. Just reused the question code. Need to have an updated version :)

Comment: CS0103 The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: You have to get it from Nuget

Comment: CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why not to use `System.Text.Json` that is included?

Comment: using System.Text.Json;  => NO

Comment: `using System.Text.Json;`

`var currencies = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root[]>(data);`

Comment: var currencies = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root[]>(data);  => ok

Comment: Ivan Khorin Спасибо

Comment: Boris Sokolov Спасибо